# Does not contain a definition for 'Include' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable, string)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Por que o meu código não reconhece o método .Include("Categoria") no meu ConsoleApp? Onde estou errando?
**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1929  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and the best extension method overload 'QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'**

```
using BotRepositorio.Entidades;
using BotRepositorio.Repositorio;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CardapioRepositorio _tbCardapio = new CardapioRepositorio();

            var list = _tbCardapio.Cardapio.Include("Categoria").ToList();
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3} - {4}", item.ItemID, item.ItemCardapio, item.Preco, item.Categoria.CategoriaID, item.Categoria.Descricao);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe Cardapio.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BotRepositorio.Entidades
{
    [Table("Cardapio")]
    public class Cardapio
    {
        [Key]
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemCardapio { get; set; }
        public decimal Preco { get; set; }
        public string UrlImagem { get; set; }
        public int CategoriaID { get; set; }
        public virtual Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Classe Categoria**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace BotRepositorio.Entidades
{
    [Table("Categoria")]
    public class Categoria
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoriaID { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string UrlImagem { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable Cardapio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Classe CardapioRepositorio**

```
using BotRepositorio.Entidades;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BotRepositorio.Repositorio
{
    public class CardapioRepositorio
    {
        private readonly DbContexto db = new DbContexto();

        public IEnumerable Cardapio
        {
            get { return db.Cardapio; }
        }
    }
}
```

**Classe CategoriaRepositorio**

```
using BotRepositorio.Entidades;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BotRepositorio.Repositorio
{
    public class CategoriaRepositorio
    {
        private readonly DbContexto db = new DbContexto();

        public IEnumerable Categorias
        {
            get { return db.Categoria; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente utilizar o [AsQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = _tbCardapio.Cardapio.AsQueryable().Include("Categoria").ToList();
```

Ele converte um `IEnumerable` para um `IQueryable`. Da mesmo forma que o `ToList` faz, porem ao contrário.

Comment: Obrigada Francisco, funcionou!!